# Display path of file in status bar

Tags: emacs

GNU Emacs 23.1.1

I am wondering is there a way to display the path of the file in the status bar, instead of just the filename.

I have to open many files in many directories, and sometimes I forget what directory they are in. Just easier to display the some of the path in the status bar if that is possible.

Sometimes my directory paths are very long.

for example

```
/projects/clientserver/trunk/src/client/client.c
```

like this in the status bar, just display the last two directories.

```
/src/client/client.c
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What you are asking is to change the buffer name. You can customize how buffers are named using [uniquify](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html). It has several methods for making unique buffer names. The most obvious choice for you is 'forward' which gives exactly what you ask -- prefix the buffer name with part of the path as a prefix.

However, this has a potentially unwanted side effect. Normally, buffer names are made unique by appending a suffix. When you do 'c-x b' to switch buffers, if you type "foo" and you have both "foo" and "foo<1>" you will be shown the common prefix and be given the ability to supply the suffix. So, 'c-x b foo' will let you do completion where you see a list of all of the "foo" buffers.

If you use uniqueify in 'forward' mode, you'll have buffer names of the form "bar/foo" and "baz/foo". Now, 'c-x b foo' won't take you to a foo buffer, or allow you to do completion to get a list of foo buffers. You must remember the prefix that is added to each buffer name.

My advice is to use the 'reverse' mode of uniqify, which uses the directory path as a suffix. It's perhaps slightly less intuitive, but easier to use in practice. So now you would have buffers like "foo\bar" and "foo\baz", again giving you the advantage of being able to do 'c-x b foo' and getting a list of all buffers with a filename of "foo".

So, add this to your .emacs file and see if you like the behavior:

```
(require 'uniquify)
(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'reverse)
```

Comment: Just syntax correction: use `uniquify-buffer-name-style` instead of `uniqueify-buffer-name-style`.

Comment: You can use "M-x customize-option RET uniquify-buffer-name-style RET" to choose the behaviour, which also provides a quick explanation of them (FWIW, I prefer post-forward-angle-brackets, which gives "filename<parent/dir>").

Comment: Enabling ido-mode with `(require 'ido)` and `(ido-mode t)` in your .emacs (see http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) will allow you to type 'C-x b foo' and still end up at the foo buffer as well. If you have multiple buffers with 'foo' in them, while using ido 'C-s' will cycle through them.

Comment: As @egor7 points out, this answer appears to have a typo and should be fixed.  Using `uniqueify-buffer-name-style` didn't work for me, while using `uniquify-buffer-name-style` did.

Comment: It didn't make any change, where the filename shown on the bottom of the `emacs` @Bryan Oakley

Answer (score 27):

If you are ok with seeing this as the frame title instead of in the status bar, which I personally prefer because it is less cluttered and is useful also when switching windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, etc., then you can add something like the following to your `.emacs` file without installing any extensions:

```
;; Disable loading of “default.el” at startup,
;; in Fedora all it does is fix window title which I rather configure differently
(setq inhibit-default-init t)

;; SHOW FILE PATH IN FRAME TITLE
(setq-default frame-title-format "%b (%f)")
```

`%b` will show the buffer name as usual, and `%f` the full file path. You can of course change the order, add text in between, remove `%b`, etc.

Comment: Even with uniquify, this is super-helpful with my xming setup, which had been naming the frames something useless.

Comment: this is what I need, simple and beautiful

Comment: Worked for me in Spacemacs under OSX even without the first `setq`. Brilliant!

Answer (score 8):

This one works well for me for setting the full path in the frame:

```
(setq frame-title-format
  '(:eval
    (if buffer-file-name
        (replace-regexp-in-string
         "\\\\" "/"
         (replace-regexp-in-string
          (regexp-quote (getenv "HOME")) "~"
          (convert-standard-filename buffer-file-name)))
      (buffer-name))))
```

Answer (score 5):

[Uniquify](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html) should pretty much do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation for the variable 
  'frame-title-format'
It will point you to the variable
  'mode-line-format'
which details the options for setting your title