# why my frame-title-format does not work?

Tags: emacs, centos, elisp, fedora, redhat

my emacs' version: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.9) of 2014-05-21 on buildvm-07.phx2.fedoraproject.org

I hope Emacs's title display the absolute path of the current file. I wrote the following contents (from internet):

```
;;;Emacs title bar to reflect file name
(defun frame-title-string ()
   "Return the file name of current buffer, using ~ if under home directory"
(let
  ((fname (or
             (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))
             (buffer-name))))
 ;;let body
  (when (string-match (getenv "HOME") fname)
    (setq fname (replace-match "~" t t fname))        )
  fname))

 ;;; Title = 'system-name File: foo.bar'
(setq frame-title-format '("" system-name "  File: "(:eval (frame-title-string))))
```

before reinstalling FC20 + Emacs, the above content was able to work correctly. Now it does not work except that I open .emacs and eval frame-title-format manually, I do not know why I must manually eval it?

Comment: If the code works when you evaluate it manually, the problem is most likely located elsewhere. Do you get an error when you start Emacs? Is there other code in your init file that could cause this etc? A good way to find the problem is to cut down your init file to a bare minimum. If it works, then extended it until the problem reappears, that way you could narrow down the problem.

Comment: there is no any error when starting Emacs. For excluding the impact of the other code, my .emacs only has the above code now, but I got the same result.

Comment: Are you sure the init file is read? (You could add `(message "I'm here")` to it and check the `*Messages*` buffer afterwards. Also, there might be a system init file installed on the system that overrides your setting?

Comment: yes, I added (message "come here here here") after (setq frame-title-format ...) and it was appeared in `*Messages*`. Now I want to force eval (setq frame-title-format ...) in .emacs, what should I do? Thanks

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but you can just use `abbreviate-file-name`, instead of trying to match env var `HOME` etc.

Comment: I have not found why it has not works, but this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009623/1054800) works!

Answer (score 1):

I was affected by the same problem.  On CentOS 7 and Fedora 21 systems, I found that `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/default.el` overrides `frame-title-format` (and nothing else).  Presumably Fedora 20 has the same issue.  The same file contains instructions for disabling this ("Setting `inhibit-default-init` non-nil in `~/.emacs`") which worked for me.

The answer that @abelard20008 refers to does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue after upgrading to `GNU Emacs 29.0.50 (build 3, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2021-12-07`

The solution was to set `icon-title-format` too.

```lisp
;; No hostname in frame title
;; Without setting the `icon-title-format`. The window title will revert
;; back to its original value after loosing its focus.
(setq frame-title-format '("" invocation-name " - " "%b"))
(setq icon-title-format '("" invocation-name " - " "%b"))
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532502/6000005

Answer (score 0):

Sounds some other code you are loading is setting the frame name.  Note from the doc string of `frame-title-format`:

> It is used only on frames for
>   which no explicit name has been set (see `modify-frame-parameters').

To find the code that does this, bisect your init file recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this to my .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda ()
                 (setq frame-title-format "%b")
))
```